# Read the data from the CSV File and it should automatically generate the EMAIL_ID to the JSP Page

Tags: java, jsp

I have a two textboxes, namely `LVPL_name` and `Email_ID`.

If I select any name from the dropdown list of the `LVPL_name` it should automatically generate the respective email ID from the CSV file and display it in the JSP page.

My sample code:

```
try { 
    String fileName = "LVPL_names.csv";
    CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(fileName ));
    String[] rows = new CSVReader(reader).readEmail_ID();
    if (x == Aarthi) { 
        System.out.println("Selected LVPL_name"+name.index of (Email_ID));
    } else { 
        System.out.println("Enter the Email_ID"); 
    } 
} catch() {

}
```

And my Excel sheet is:

```
 LVPL_name   Email ID 
-----------------------
aaaaa1      aaaaa1@sap.com 
aaaaa2      aaaaa2@sap.com 
aaaaa3      aaaaa3@sap.com 
aaaaa4      aaaaa4@sap.com 
aaaaa5      aaaaa5@sap.com
```

I think something is wrong in my code.

Comment: @RadhikaEmmadi in the future, please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38349727/edit) the code and data into your question, with the 'edit' link underneath it.

Answer (score 2):

You have to do this through `ajax` / `servlet` / `xhr` requests. Here's an example of `xhr` request.

*For following code to work properly as it as(unedited), You must have your CSV file in `C:` drive. Your CSV filename must be `mydata.csv`. And, also, you should place `index.jsp` and `getEmail.jsp` in the same folder.*

**index.jsp**

```
<%@page import="java.io.File"%>
<%@page import="java.io.FileReader"%>
<%@page import="com.opencsv.CSVReader"%>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>

<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function selected(value){
                var xhReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhReq.open("GET", "getEmail.jsp?lvpl=" + value, false);
                xhReq.send(null);
                var serverResponse = xhReq.responseText;
                document.getElementById('textbox').value = serverResponse;
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>

<%
    // Varaibles
    String lvpl, email;
    int counter = 0;
    CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(new File("C://mydata.csv")));
    String[] data;
%>

        <select onchange="selected(this.value)">
<%
    // READING TO CSV TO CREATE DATA IN SELECT BOX
    while ((data = reader.readNext()) != null) {

        // Skips CSV File Headings: LVPL and EMAIL_ID 
        if(counter == 0){
            counter++;      // Increase it so that it can't come in this block again
            continue;
        }

        // CSV FILE DATA AS READ BY CSVREADER
        lvpl = data[0];         // LVPL
        email = data[1];        // EMAIL
%>
            <option><%=lvpl%></option>
<%      
    }
%>
        </select>

        <input id="textbox" type="text" placeholder="email will show in here">

    </body>
</html>
```

**getEmail.jsp**

```
<%@page import="java.io.FileReader"%>
<%@page import="java.io.File"%>
<%@page import="com.opencsv.CSVReader"%>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%
    // get lvpl from received request
    String lvplReceived = request.getParameter("lvpl");

    // Reading CSV
    String lvpl = "", email = "";
    int counter = 0;
    boolean lvplFound = false;  // becomes true when lvpl matches selected lvpl

    CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(new File("C://mydata.csv")));
    String[] nextLine;
    while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {

        /* Skips CSV File Headers: LVPL and EMAIL_ID */
        if(counter == 0){
            counter++;
            continue;
        }

        // CSV FILE DATA
        lvpl = nextLine[0];         // LVPL
        email = nextLine[1];        // EMAIL

        if(lvpl.equals(lvplReceived)){      // if this lvpl matches with selected lvpl
            lvplFound = true;
            break;
        }

    }

    if(lvplFound){      // print email of matched lvpl
        out.print(email);
    } else {
        out.print("not found");
    }
%>
```

**tested with mydata.csv**

```
LVPL    EMAIL
aaaaa1  aaaaa1@sap.com
aaaaa2  aaaaa2@sap.com
aaaaa3  aaaaa3@sap.com
aaaaa4  aaaaa4@sap.com
aaaaa5  aaaaa5@sap.com
```

**If this didn't work the way you wanted or if you don't understand this code, please feel free to contact me through comments**

Useful Links:

- [Ajax Video Tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGDiJSXfsJTASx9eMq_HlenQ)
- [OpenCSV Usage Guide](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/)
- [Ajax Example for Java Web Applications](http://www.javatpoint.com/ajax-example-with-database)

*Note: If you're learning JSP now, I suggest you to move to JSTL. JSP is no longer used and it was deprecated 10 years ago because it couln't match Microsoft's ASP. If you continue to learn JSP, it will not benefit you in future especially in India, I can't believe people there are still teaching a 10 year old technology. Here's a [JSTL book](https://onceavocisunl.files.wordpress.com/2007/12/jstl_ebook.pdf) to get you started.*